# Groupby Plot - Include Subgroup Name

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to plot two columns of a time series based on a groupby of a third column. It works as intended more or less, but I can't tell which subgroup is being plotted in the output as it is not included in the legend or anywhere else in the graphs outputted.

Is there a way to include the subgroup name in the graphs outputted?

This is what I've attempted on the dataframe as follows:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LYgB.png)

`awareness.groupby('campaign_name')['sum_purchases_value','sum_ad_spend'].plot(figsize=(20,8), legend=True);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grouped = awareness.groupby('campaign_name')
titles = [name for name,data in grouped]
plots = grouped['sum_purchases_value',
                'sum_ad_spend'].plot(figsize=(20,8), legend=True)

for plot, label in zip(plots, titles):
    plot.set(title = label)
```

The pandas plot function returns a Series of matplotlib subplot objects, so using the for loop you can customize whatever you like (x labels, y labels, font size, etc.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Great first contribution to the site.

Comment: Thanks! I've certainly gotten a lot of help from this site over the years, so it's about time I started paying it forward.